# Generating a grid (Array) of Tetris Pieces

Tags: c++, procedural-generation

What I want to do is quite self explanatory. Just like the title states. I want to code something that will generate a grid which contains is filled of Tetris pieces.
However some conditions must be met :

- Having no empty holes for the final grid (all sections of the grid filled)
- Having no blocks sticking out (e.g. a long tetris block sticking out of the square grid)

I have tried to approach the problem using my way since the methods used online are too complicated for me.
The first idea I had was to use a 2D array which each row will be gone through to have some generation algorithm. The next row will depend on the previous row. Such as making a 2x2 block. It will check if the current row position is empty, if it is then it will check if the previous row is empty. If it is then it will make keep note that this point is being used. But if the previous block is already been used. It will check what kind of block it is and depending on what information is on that position. It will either be a connecting piece of just a blank piece.

The second idea i have in mind is similar to the first idea.
That is, it will also go through each row but this way is dependent on maths.
Lets say we have a 10x10 grid. We can say each row is made of 10 blocks. And from that we can say each tetris shape is made of miniblocks. E.g the 2x2 block is made of 2x2 small blocks.
So from this we can, go through the first row and for the first 2 blocks of the 10 keep note in the array that we want to generate the a 2x2 tetris block. And we can go to the next row and we know that the previous row there was a 2x2 tetris block that is need to be finished creating in the second row. And so we repeat this to try and get a filled grid of tetris blocks.

Sorry I am not good at explaining/implementating/reading code. Sorry for the inconvenience.
I have been suggested by some people to look at Tetris AI. And maybe use the AI to solve my problem. But I'm not good with reading other people's code. Plus it isn't in the language i understand. And i dont have anyone to go through the code with me.
 So i prefer to use my own idea since i know what is going on. But i don't know how to implement the code.

If there is anyone who could help me in any way it would be my honor.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you may want to add an additional constraint. As stated, the problem has a trivial solution. If the rectangle is to be completely filled by tetrominos with no gaps or overhang, then its area must be a multiple of 4. That means either one side length is a multiple of 4, and you can tile the whole rectangle with 4x1 line pieces, or both side lengths are multiples of 2, which means you can tile the whole rectangle with 2x2 squares. I expect though that you actually want some variation in the tiles used to fill the space, so you'll want to add more criteria for what makes a valid solution.

Comment: Yes I do want many variations. Like the different tetris shapes, also with the addition of rotation.
But the biggest problem is, i dont know how to code it.
I really need help for that